# Material Guidelines for Alerts

Tags: material-design, alerts

Aside from Bootstrap's alerts page I am unable to find any material guidelines for alerts that we can use in the development of a notification bar.

Are there any good guidelines out there based on user behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Material guidelines have 3 types of notification components.

Under the **[Snackbar section](https://material.io/design/components/snackbars.html#anatomy)**, it recommends which component to use based on the amount of interruption or attention that's needed from the user:
[image]

I don't know your use case, or your definition of 'Alert', but you have two other options:

**[Alert Dialog](https://material.io/design/components/dialogs.html#alert-dialog)**

> Alert dialogs interrupt users with urgent information, details, or actions.

**[Banners](https://material.io/design/components/banners.html#usage)**

> A banner displays an important, succinct message, and provides actions for users to address (or dismiss the banner). It requires a user action to be dismissed.

Comment: Many thanks for this Mike, that is very useful. The alert I am implementing is a banner with an icon, message and dismissal cross. In our case the banner is above/at the top of the top bar.